# Safari foreignObject getBBox is wrong

Tags: svg, safari

In Safari the getBBox of foreignObject element always returns 0 for x and 0 for y. See the following [example](https://jsbin.com/wicaxog/2/edit?html,js,output) (open in safari). Notice `console.log(document.querySelector('foreignObject').getBBox());`
prints

```
{
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
```

In chrome and firefox it works as expected.
Is there any workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the foreignObject in a `<g>` and get the bounding box of the wrapper.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.foreignObjectWrapper').getBBox());
console.log(document.querySelector('#rect').getBBox());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
    <rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
     <g class="foreignObjectWrapper">
    <foreignObject x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100">
      <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px; height:100px;">
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
     </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```