# Advantage to use "native tags" over foreignObject in a svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I created the [stackoverflow-readme-profile](https://github.com/johannchopin/stackoverflow-readme-profile) project that create a personalized Stackoverflow's profile as a svg image. I spend a lot of time to build it using "native svg tags" like the following:

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="86" viewBox="0 0 300 86" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: visible;">
  <rect width="300" height="80" rx="5" ry="5" fill="orange"></rect> 
  <rect width="140" height="40" x="10" y="20" fill="yellow"></rect> 
  <rect width="140" height="40" x="150" y="20" fill="blue"></rect> 
</svg>
```

**➜** [Result](https://jsfiddle.net/tLa02w67/20/)

Where with a `<foreignObject>` tag I could use handy css properties like `flexbox` alignment:

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="86" viewBox="0 0 300 86" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: visible;">
  <foreignObject width="300" height="80">
    <div style="width: 100%; height:100%; border-radius: 5px; background: orange; display: flex; padding: 20px 10px; box-sizing: border-box;">
      <div style="width: 100%; background: yellow;"></div>
      <div style="width: 100%; background: blue;"></div>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

**➜** [Result](https://jsfiddle.net/gy7f4pe1/20/)

Is there then a real advantage to using a "native" svg or have I just lost a huge amount of time?

Comment: You'll find a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221528) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313873) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820748) about the buggy implementation of `foreignObject` in Safari. At least those you would avoid. BTW, all the attributes your `<rect>` have can be written as CSS properties nowadays.

Comment: Try drawing a Bezier curve and then tell me whether a path or html and css is easier.

Comment: @ccprog Right browser compatibility is a big risk to take in this topic

Comment: @RobertLongson you got a good point